# Multiples insert con mysql, sin esperar el hilo de ejecución?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedure, insert

Mi inquietud es la siguiente: 
Tras realizar una operación cualquiera, debo realizar registros en una `tabla "notificación"` que depende de la cantidad de registros de otra `tabla (usuarios)`. Eso lo he realizado con una sentencia `INSERT SELECT`.

Pero el problema es que ha media que incrementa la cantidad de usuario, el proceso es cuestión demora más. Mi idea era dejar encargado al servidor de realizar estas inserciones, y seguir el hilo de ejecución con el proceso.

He leído sobre `procedimientos almacenados`, aunque como soy nuevo con esto, no estoy seguro si tiene esa característica o existe alguna otra funcionalidad en mysql que realice esto.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: un procedimiento almacenado, es una series de consultas que puede ser parametrizada y tiene parametros. Es lo mismo (o similar) a las consultas que estas haciendo. Si queres que se ejecute despues, o en otro momento, deberias pensar en un procedimiento asincronico, que se vaya ejecutando encoladamente. Desconozco si existe algo asi en php.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo php tiene un único hilo. Si llamas a un procedimiento almacenado, php igualmente, esperará a que el procedimiento termine para seguir ejecutando. Si desde php haces una llamada para cada insert, y tu plan es que el procedimiento almacenado resuelva todos los inserts con una llamada podés tener una mejora en los tiempos dado qeu hay menos idas y vueltas a la base de datos pero dentro del mismo hilo de ejecución.

Comment: De hecho solo es una llamada, la consulta esta hecha con un insert select.

Answer (score 1):

Espero uses una versión reciente MySQL que soporta triggers. En la documentación de MySQL viene información al respecto (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) en tu caso sería algo parecido a:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER insertar_notificacion AFTER INSERT ON users
[.... BODY ... código para insertar información para la tabla notificación]
```

Se usa un lenguaje especial, es muy parecido al que se usa también en postgreSQL.Hay palabras reservadas como "*NEW*" o "*OLD*" que se usan para asignar o obtener valores de los campos de las tablas modificadas que "disparan el evento".

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO notificacion SET notificacion_campo = NEW.campo_insertado_en_user; 
  END;
```